# Circle CI integration: composer needs to be authenticated

Tags: magento2, integration

I'm setting up Circle CI with Magento 2. Circle has Composer available out of the box, but I'm not sure how to add the `repo.magento.com` credentials during my builds.

Circle CI has a setting page where you can add Checkout SSH keys, SSH Permissions, API Permission, etc., but I'm not sure if any of these are for Composer. Normally, you would need to update `~/.composer/auth.json` with your credentials to access `repo.magento.com`.

Has anybody set this up properly?

Error I'm getting during the Circle CI build.

```
Installing magento/framework (100.1.1)
Downloading: Connecting...

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
The 'https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/framework/magento-framework-  
100.1.1.0.zip' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Comment: check first url : https://repo.magento.com/ is open or not in your system.

Comment: @SHPatel, I don't follow. My local machine is configured to work with `repo.magento.com`. It's the Circle CI build that needs it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, the solution is to actually make the `auth.json` file available in your repo and create a dependency in `circle.yml`.

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - mkdir -p ~/.composer && cp /path/to/composers/auth.json ~/.composer/auth.json
```

Comment: You could probably generate it in circle.yml using Circle's private environment variables as placeholders right?